# Datatable ajax error without error detail

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatable, timeout, firebug

The process falls into the error(jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown) handler.

When I console.log the variables I get :

```
jqXHR: {
    readyState: 0,
    responseText: "",
    status: 0,
    statusText: "error"
    //and other meaningless prototype functions
}
textStatus: "error"
errorThrown: ""
```

I have 2 Datatables on the same page, and the other one is loading properly.

Console shows a weird thing :

- The first datatable ajax call is OK (HTTP 200)
- The second one with the error has no HTTP code and the response is empty. But when I open the call in a new tab, it's working as expected, returning a JSON response.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was linked to the Apache2 web server.

I don't know why, but restarting it solved the issue.